# When i put MouseListener the class become Error

Tags: java, swing

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.sql.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   import java.awt.Image;
   import java.awt.Toolkit;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;


   public class Profile extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseLIstener{

       JLabel home = new JLabel("Home");
       JLabel pro = new JLabel("Profile");    

       JTextField search = new JTextField("");

       JButton update = new JButton("Update Info");
       ImageIcon log = new ImageIcon("mini.png");
       JLabel logo = new JLabel(log, JLabel.CENTER);

       ImageIcon ban = new ImageIcon("cover.jpg");
       JLabel bann = new JLabel(ban, JLabel.CENTER);
       ImageIcon ppic = new ImageIcon("Koala.jpg");
       JLabel profile = new JLabel(ppic, JLabel.CENTER);
       ImageIcon menu1 = new ImageIcon("fbMenu.png");
       JLabel menu = new JLabel(menu1, JLabel.CENTER);

       Container c;
       Connection con;
       Statement st;
       ResultSet rs;
       int ctr;

       public Profile() {

           Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("fb.png");
           setIconImage(icon);
           this.setTitle("Profile");
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           this.setResizable(false);
           this.setLayout(null);
           this.setSize(600, 500);
           this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


           c=this.getContentPane();
           c.setLayout(null);
           this.add(update);
           c.add(profile);
           c.add(logo);
           c.add(search);
           c.add(home);
           c.add(pro);
           c.add(menu);
           c.add(bann);
           profile.setBounds(20, 150, 150, 150);
           bann.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 200);
           menu.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 40);
           home.setBounds(360, 10, 35, 25);
           pro.setBounds(410, 10, 40, 25);
           update.setBounds(300, 160, 110, 35);
           search.setBounds(90, 10, 230, 25);
           logo.setBounds(60, 10, 25, 25);

           update.addActionListener(this); 

       }


       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               Object o = e.getSource();
           if(o==update)
           {    
               Update j= new Update();              
               j.setVisible(traue);
               this.setVisible(false);
               j.setVisible(true);
           }

       }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Profile pr = new Profile();
           pr.setVisible(true);
       }

   }
```

Comment: Please put some effort into your question. Don't just post "error" and a wall of code -- tell us some of the details of your problem. Sorry but this question is the ultimate of lazy. Please prove this wrong.

Comment: What type of error you got?

Comment: You used the wrong tag. Just use the code button `{}` to format. Do not make it bold. I'm not going to clean that one up, I wish to go to bed soon.

Comment: Again, take a look at [How to write Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and implement the contract specified by the `MouseListener` interafce. You may also wish to take a look at the [Interfaces tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Comment: "Profile is not abstract and does not override abstract method mouseExited(MouseEvent in MouseListener" thats the error

Comment: And we **already told you** what your problem was in your last closed question, but you just chose to ignore it. Why? Why bother trying to help if you just ignore the help? Again, look at @MadProgrammer's links, again, your class must implement all methods of any interface it is declared to implement. Yours implements **none** of the MouseListener methods.

Answer (score 2):

From your code below:

```
public class Profile extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseLIstener{
```

You type the wrong MouseListener name as **MouseLIstener**.

Change

```
 MouseLIstener
```

to

```
 MouseListener
```

and then add unimplement methods below, it will work for your program.

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```